# Implementation of Python's re.split in Clojure (with capturing parentheses)

Tags: python, regex, clojure

If you use capturing parenthesis in the regular expression pattern in Python's `re.split()` function, it will include the matching groups in the result ([Python's documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split)).

I need this in my Clojure code and I didn't find an implementation of this, nor a Java method for achieving the same result.

```
(use '[clojure.string :as string :only [blank?]])

(defn re-tokenize [re text]
  (let [matcher (re-matcher re text)]
    (defn inner [last-index result]
      (if (.find matcher)
        (let [start-index (.start matcher)
              end-index (.end matcher)
              match (.group matcher)
              insert (subs text last-index start-index)]
          (if (string/blank? insert)
            (recur end-index (conj result match))
            (recur end-index (conj result insert match))))
        (conj result (subs text last-index))))
    (inner 0 [])))
```

Example:

```
(re-tokenize #"(\W+)" "...words, words...")
  => ["..." "words" ", " "words" "..." ""]
```

How could I make this simpler and / or more efficient (maybe also more Clojure-ish)?

Comment: For what it's worth, [clojure.contrib.string/partition](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.string/partition) does this exactly.

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust you implementation to be a lazy-seq for some added performance:

```lisp
(use '[clojure.string :as string :only [blank?]])

(defn re-tokenizer [re text]
  (let [matcher (re-matcher re text)]
    ((fn step [last-index]
       (when (re-find matcher)
         (let [start-index (.start matcher)
               end-index (.end matcher)
               match (.group matcher)
               insert (subs text last-index start-index)]
           (if (string/blank? insert)
             (cons match (lazy-seq (step end-index)))
             (cons insert (cons match (lazy-seq (step end-index))))))))
     0)))
```

This implementation will be more efficient as the results will only be calculated as needed. For instance if you only needed the first 10 results from a really long string you can use:

```lisp
(take 10 (re-tokenize #"(\W+)" really-long-string)
```

and only the first 10 elements will be computed.